# Aggregation of rows with interchanged column values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

My input table looks something like this

```
Source   Destn   Value
-----------------------
A        B        1
B        A        2
```

Desired output ->  A   B   3

Whats the appropriate query to obtain the above mentioned result in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Source < Destn THEN Source ELSE Destn END,
       CASE WHEN Source >= Destn THEN Source ELSE Destn END,
       SUM(Value)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Source < Destn THEN Source ELSE Destn END,
         CASE WHEN Source >= Destn THEN Source ELSE Destn END
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26970/3)

**Edit:** Credit goes to @Nick Barnes

The query can be simplified using `LEAST` and `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT least("Source","Destn"),
       greatest("Source","Destn"),
       SUM("Value")
FROM mytable
GROUP BY least("Source","Destn"),
         greatest("Source","Destn")
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/26970/4)